# Yajra OCI-8 package return ORA-01861 over a simple SELECT query

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-8

i am using laravel8 and try the yajra/oci8 packages. i can connect to db, but can not perform basic query such:

```
$pdo = DB::connection('oracle');
$data = $pdo->table('SD_WH_V')->first();
```

its always giving me :

```
Error Code : 1861 Error Message : ORA-01861: literal does not match format string Position : 7929 Statement : select * from (select * from "SD_WH_V") where rownum = 1 Bindings : [] (SQL: select * from (select * from "SD_WH_V") where rownum = 1)
```

but when i did it with oci_connect & oci_parse, it gave me the correct result

```
$s = oci_parse($conn, 'select * from (select * from "SD_WH_V") where rownum = 1');
oci_execute($s);
oci_fetch_all($s, $res)
```

my oracle config is

```
'oracle' => [
            'driver'         => 'oracle',
            'tns'            => '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.11X)(PORT = 15XX))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME =PRXX)))',
            'host'           => env('DB_HOST_ORA', ''),
            'port'           => env('DB_PORT_ORA', '1521'),
            'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE_ORA', ''),
            'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME_ORA', ''),
            'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD_ORA', ''),
            'charset'        => env('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF8'),
            'prefix'         => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'prefix_schema'  => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
            'server_version' => env('DB_SERVER_VERSION', '11g'),
            'load_balance'   => env('DB_LOAD_BALANCE', 'yes'),
            'dynamic'        => [],
            'session'        => [] 
        ]
```

my oracle db probably version 10, is there any compatibility problem with the driver/package?

Comment: i try to running the same query i did with the oci_parse, but still return the same error

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it would be nice to have the same query ran as an example - to make it as a proper [mcve]. anyway, care to share the [configuration for `DB::connection('oracle');`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/config/database.php)? you should omit the password, but share the rest.

Comment: Error you reported (ORA-01861) is raised when you do something *unexpected* when dealing with **date** datatype values. For example, this will raise it: `select to_date('20230215', 'yyyy-mon-dd') from dual`. Query you posted is just a simple `select * from ...` which can't cause such an error, so ... regarding the fact that I don't know PHP nor Laravel - I'd still say that you're blaming wrong query.

Comment: i already shared the connection config and edited the qry sample i did with oci_parse

Comment: @siapeajabole just to be sure, could you make sure whatever `NLS` config in the oracle database and the [yajra's config](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/blob/a4417bef852e4e98b7eb836dee5c46086fc74237/src/config/oracle.php) matches? it seems you can have that particular `ORA-01861` for syntax or data format errors. regarding the format, that `NLS` thingy are the only parameters that relevant in the entire yajra-laravel-dbal-symfony stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it by change the sessionVars array on file Oci8ServiceProvider.php with

```
$sessionVars = [
                'NLS_TIME_FORMAT'         => 'HH.MI.SSXFF AM',
                'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'         => 'DD-MON-RR',
                'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'    => 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM',
                'NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT' => 'HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR',
                'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'  => '.,',
            ];
```

as in the NLS config on my oracle db

Thanks a lot for the help!